# Fatigue Considerations: Over-tightened Front Derailleur Dent

Tags: steel, damage

I'm looking into purchasing a used bike to get into touring/bikepacking. There is a particularly low price Soma Double Cross Disc bike I've found on Craigslist that I think would be perfect... with one caveat. As you can see in the image below, a clamp on derailleur was over-tightened on the seat tube. My question is this: should I be worried about this too much? Would this be an easy fix for a frame builder?

Obviously, I have to go take a look at the frame and ensure that there is no cracking. This would perhaps entail removing the paint. I'm also going to consult a couple of shops in my area to get some professional opinions. In my mind, this shouldn't be a big deal on a CrMo frame. It's obviously going to reduce the life of the frame, but for a mere $500 I think I'm okay with that.

[image: Frame Damage]

Comment: A mere $500, that's $499.5 too much. Trust that frame to break!

Comment: The asking price is almost retail for a NEW Soma frame. Something is not right!

Comment: @Rider_X I think OP means $500 for the complete bike.

Answer (score 3):

*Personally* I'd stay far, far away, it's not worth the risk. Especially as you intend to load the bike up for bike-packing.

Cracks are not the problem. Structural tubes are severely weakened when they are buckled inwards too much. That looks like too much to me. Also, such deformation is likely to have work-hardened the steel.

The only way to repair this would be to replace the whole seat tube - which would cost more than the frame.

Comment: Chain stays are deformed/indented right at the factory to a similar degree. If you wanted to repair it you wouldn’t have to replace the whole tube, you could solder/weld a brace (i.e. a lengthwise halved piece of tube of the right length and diameter) in place.